# Initializing Direct3D without a HWND

Tags: winapi, direct3d, firebreath, hwnd, gdi

Currently I'm using Direct2D for rendering 2D frames, but I realized that it's not supported in Windows XP (or anywhere with DirectX < 10), and now I'm looking for a way to support DirectX 9.

My scenario is not a simple one, and to cut to the chase my problem is that I do not have a HWND which I can use to initialize direct3d, however I do have an HDC.
This is what I'm doing with direct2d:

```
ID2D1DCRenderTarget *renderTarget = NULL;
HRESULT hr = FACTORY->CreateDCRenderTarget(&RENDER_TARGET_PROPERTIES, &renderTarget);
renderTarget->BindDC(this->hdc, &this->viewport);
renderTarget->BeginDraw();
...
```

I'm looking for an equivalent thing that will work with DirectX 9 and that allows to use HDC and not HWND.

I've searched a lot, and found other question regarding this issue, but I can't find a satisfying solution, the only thing I managed to find is offscreen rendering, but I couldn't find any good source for examples or explanations about that, what I did find included the use of an HWND to initiate d3d9.

Any ideas on how I can manage to render 2D frame (with transparency) on XP?
Thanks.

---

## Edit

`WindowFromDC` returns null for the HDC I pass it.
Here's my code:

```
HWND hwnd = WindowFromDC(hdc);

LPDIRECT3D9 d3d = Direct3DCreate9(D3D_SDK_VERSION);
LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 d3ddev;
D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS d3dpp;

LPD3DXSPRITE sprite;
LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9 texture;
D3DXVECTOR3 imagepos(0, 0, 0);

ZeroMemory(&d3dpp, sizeof(d3dpp));
d3dpp.Windowed = False;
d3dpp.SwapEffect = D3DSWAPEFFECT_DISCARD;
d3dpp.hDeviceWindow = hwnd;

if (SUCCEEDED(d3d->CreateDevice(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT,
    D3DDEVTYPE_HAL,
    hwnd,
    D3DCREATE_SOFTWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING,
    &d3dpp,
    &d3ddev))) {

    ....
}
```

The `hwnd` is null and so the call to `d3d->CreateDevice` fails (I think that's the reason).
As for the `HDC`, it exists and when I use it with direct2d it works fine.

Any ideas how to bypass this problem?

---

## 2nd Edit

Thanks to @RogerRowland I've discovered that the HDC that I get is a memory HDC (`OBJ_MEMDC`).
I guess that it's what the browser/firebreath is giving me, but it works well when I use it with Direct2D (like in the code from my first posting) and also when I try regular Win32 rendering (with `BitBlt` and all).

I can't seem to find a way to use Direct3D 9 with only the HDC I get, and so I'm currently working on a workaround which creates a new hidden window in which I'll do the rendering and then will copy the result to the HDC I have (BitBlting probably).
Even if this solution works I still don't like it very much so if anyone has another approach for dealing with this problem I'd love to know.

Comment: [`WindowFromDC`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145201.aspx)?

Comment: Why do you not have a window?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - Because it's in a NPAPI browser windowless plugin, I just found out today that it may still be an option to get a hold on the HWND but I need to make sure.
@IInspectable - Thanks! Wasn't aware of that method, should have searched for `how to get HDC from HWND`. I will check that out.

Comment: I tried `WindowFromDC` but it does not work (I edited my question with more info). Any ideas? thanks!

Comment: Is the DC a "real" DC or a memory DC?

Comment: Note - you can see if it's a real DC by checking that `GetObjectType((HGDIOBJ)hDC) == OBJ_DC`. If it's a mem dc, it will be `OBJ_MEMDC`.

Comment: Thanks for that angle @RogerRowland, turns out that I do get a memory HDC.. I updated my question with a 2nd edit.

Comment: Yes, I think your workaround is the only way to go now, without a window, you can't get DX9 rendering directly.

Comment: Do *not* get the HWND for a windowless plugin, it belongs to the browser

Comment: Yeah, I got that part, but I was trying to get a hand on any usable HWND... If you're here, how is it that the HDC that I get (`windowlessWindow->getHDC()`) is a memory HDC? Thanks.